# Install boost version 1.40

Tags: c++, boost, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I am using a server running with Ubuntu 12.04

I want to install the boost libraries in it. I know

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

will make the work done, but it installs the latest version version 1.52 or above.

But I need to install the particular version 1.40 as there is a problem in a simulator which I am using for my academic purpose. What is the particular command for that so that I can install the boost libraries along with the other requirements for it like the linking files

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely you will have to download and build the sources yourself

Comment: You can download required binaries from here - http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/. But you would have to remove the current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick answer:** `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev= 1.40.0.1`

If it doesn't work, continue reading.

The **`apt-get` does support installing a particular version** of a package `as long as it is in an archive that apt knows about`. From the `apt-get` manpage:

```
A specific version of a package can be selected for installation by following the 
package name with an equals and the version of the package to select. This will 
cause that version to be located and selected for install. Alternatively a specific       
distribution can be selected by following the package name with a slash and the version of 
the distribution or the Archive name (stable, frozen, unstable).
```

For e.g. if you wanted to install **apache 2.20** for Ubuntu, you would do something like:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.20-1ubuntu1
```

Note that you may **need to do some dependency resolution** on your own in this case, but if there are any problems apt-get will tell you what is causing them. For e.g.(on 11.04)

```
sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.20-1ubuntu1 \
                     apache2.2-common=2.2.20-1ubuntu1 \
                     apache2.2-bin=2.2.20-1ubuntu1 \
                     apache2-mpm-worker=2.2.20-1ubuntu1
```

**Note:** You must first check if build 1.40 is still available. For that use:

```
aptitude search libboost
```

If aptitude search command don't give you sufficient results, try `sudo aptitude update` and then run `aptitude search` again.

You might have to investigate whether debs from earlier Ubuntu versions can be installed. i.e. remove the current package, download the debs and try installing them. But there could be dependency on older versions of the standard library.If so, you can probably try downloading the source from `launchpad`.

As a **last resort**, download from **boost.org and build it - painfully!**

**EDIT:** I see you have asked the same question on ubuntu forums and it seems that you have 1.48 as the default. You might have to build the library itself. Can you try this `apt-get`

```
sudo apt-get install libboost1.40-all-dev=1.40.0-4ubuntu4
```

If this doesn't work, you will have to build it and install it yourself. You can download the source from

**Download source (1.40.0):** [libboost 1.40.0 source files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.40.0/)

After it's installed, run the following command to hold your installed version, preventing the package manager from automatically updating it in the future:

```
sudo echo "[packagename] hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Source:[How to Downgrade Packages on Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: the aptitude search is returning packages for 1.46,1.48. How can I install 1.40

Answer (score 0):

Generally you download sources, build it (some parts are not just headers like filesystem on Windows). Then you can select which subset of libraries you want to install (you can make compact version with only what you need). Then by invoking bootstrap script you build it to another directory this subset of libraries you want and then you invoke install.

Here is a pretty good description how to do it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1180792

Comment: Isn't there command to select the version like for gcc we can use sudo apt-get install gcc-4.5

Comment: It might be, see user2339071 response. Building from sources are always possible.